# JBoss edit files inside .WAR 

Tags: xhtml, jboss, edit

Is it possible to edit `.xhtml` or `.css` files under JBoss like in Tomcat - on fly?
Without rebuilding of WAR file.

Tried extracted folder,like described here : [exploded folder](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExplodedDeployment)
Didn't help.

Tried plugin under Eclipse for JBoss integration.
Got `.sar` file,but it's not recognized by JBoss.

JBoss version is `7.1.1`

Comment: IIRC you can just unzip the war file and change the files directly. In this case, of course, you have to keep your changed files and your project file in sync. I remember, though years ago, that I got eclipse and jboss working with hot deployment..

Comment: By the way, most IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans) allow you to deploy the exploded package instead of the zipped .war directly. Maybe you should give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found way how to edit resources.
There is actually,extracted folder,resided here:

```
$your_jboss_project_folder$\standalone\tmp\vfs
```

this folder can hold name,for instance,`tempbecfe4f41f983f15`
There you can find extracted `WAR` folder and jar,if you add it to `\deployments` folder

Comment: The tmp folder is not the right way to modify the JSP's as you risk loosing the changes. You should be able to deploy an exploded WAR and make changes to the actual war file itself.

Comment: This is really not the way to do this! When doing development on WAR archives, you should use an exploded directory.

Comment: parasietje, I know, i tried it, if you read my post.For now this is only solution that wroks for me.However,further,i redo it...

Comment: jBug,I know,that I should,but i couldn't.I mentioned this in me post with links. I got `.war` and `war.deployed` under `/deployment`.Both uneditable.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to configure the web subsystem to enable development so that JBoss can look for modification. The configuration you'll need to setup is

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
...
    <configuration>
        <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
    </configuration>
</subsystem>
```

Refer [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/170748?tstart=0) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/jsp.html) for more information

Comment: jBug,thank you for point,but the main issue is that I can't edit `jsp` at all as far have no extracted folder under `/deployments` Jboss folder as it's under Tomcat `/webapps`.There are 2 archives:`<appName>.WAR` and `<appName>.WAR.deployed`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is by using an exploded folder.
Please ask another question with title "Exploded folder does not work in JBoss".

Your evaluation of "Didn't help." is a little short to allow us to solve your problem.

- Did you use `myFolder.war` as the folder name?
- Does `myFolder.war` contain a directory `WEB-INF`, with a `web.xml` ?
- Are there any errors in the JBoss server.log?
- Maybe you disabled the JBoss deployment scanner?

Comment: 1. i used such naming 2. it contains 3. no errors. 4 doesn't know anything about deployments scanner